# View network activity for browser child window

Tags: google-chrome, networking, firebug, monitoring

I need to reverse-engineer some javascript application which does authorization using facebook auth.

Facebook auth window pops up, asks for my permissions, and gets closed instantly, so I am unable to grasp anything from the performed action, as it's too fast.

The problem is that neither Chrome DevTools, nor Firefox Firebug does display network activity for child windows like OAuth permission.

Is there a way to enable FULL network log? An extension, whatever? (It better be free and easy to use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows, you need [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).  If you're not, you'll have to settle for [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).  Wireshark is more-general and an amazing tool, but Fiddler does a much better job for HTTP and SSL conversations like you're going to be examining.